# override BackButton press in SearchView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, searchview

I'm getting mad with using `SearchView` in a `fragment` and the back button is always shown whatever i touched the search bar or not  and i do the search but i have a problem that back button do nothing but clear the text in search i would like to use it to switch also between `fragments`. I've tried many solutions in stack overflow questions but seems not solving my issue. 
the code after adding `toolbar` in the `fragment`:

```
    @Override
   public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu_fragment, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search_locations);
    SearchView searchView = new SearchView(((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(searchItem, searchItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW ); //searchItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW |
    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(searchItem, searchView);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // filter recycler view when query submitted
            locationStatesPreviewAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            // filter recycler view when text is changed
            Log.e("QueryChange",query);
            locationStatesPreviewAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

the `xml` file has only the search item in the menu :

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
       <item android:id="@+id/action_search_locations"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:title="@string/app_name"
       android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
       app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
       app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
       </menu>
```

Thanks.

Comment: So , what do you want to do with the back button

Comment: override to switch between fragments rather than clicking and doing nothing but clear the search which is already cleared

Comment: this example using SearchView to filter recycler view but in activity and i tried it also have the same problem. link: https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/

Comment: That's just how `SearchView` works as an options menu action `View`. If you want to keep the actual back button when the `SearchView` expands, then don't set it as an options menu item. Instead, put a `<SearchView>` directly inside a `<Toolbar>` in your layout.

Comment: that would be other thing , the idea is i need the back button to clear the search it's okay, but also i need to go back when the search out of focus and clear.. the thing that will help me if i know how to make a listener to that button so i can handle the situation myself.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. When the `SearchView` collapses, the back button should work as usual.

Comment: in my case it didn't work, it just clear the text in the SearchView and then all the clicks do nothing.

Comment: Well, when the `SearchView` is expanded, the arrow you see there isn't actually the back button. It's a separate `View` internal to `SearchView`. The real back button gets hidden, until the `SearchView` is collapsed. If your back button isn't working when the `SearchView` is collapsed, then it doesn't sound like the `SearchView` is the issue.

Comment: I have only the search view arrow which i mean (the back button) and it's always shown whatever  happen to the search expanded or collapsed may be because the menu has only one child and actually the activity which i build the fragment on without  a toolbar so this button is always shown.

Comment: Wait, no, I don't see what you mean. How does the `SearchView`'s arrow always show? Is it always pinned to the left? Or do you mean it expands and collapses with the `SearchView`?

Comment: Also, why are you creating a new `SearchView` in code there? That menu item will already have a `SearchView` action `View`. You just need to do `searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();`. I can't even get your code to work, as is, so I'm not really sure what you're observing.

Comment: I got you but even with this modification. the problem still the same.

Comment: I tried that also still the same problem.. always shown.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're actually describing. The "back button" and the `SearchView`'s close arrow are going to look exactly the same. I still think that you might just not be handling the back button appropriately, and that the `SearchView` isn't really related to the issue. What happens if you remove the `SearchView` temporarily? Does your back button work then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a problem of mis-understanding, as i thought it's the back button of the SearchView in Fragment and afterwards it was the toolbar Navigation button and after adding this lines to make it responsive and all things done ! thanks for help all.

```
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TOOLBAR");

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Back clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```